# Rails - View unseen comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Leads model which has comments. Stored in the comments model.

When users are browsing leads, I would like to show them how many new comments there are since the last time they viewed a particular lead's profile.

How would I go about this?

My initial idea is to store the last time a user browsed a lead's profile and the number of comments that come after this date would be the unread comments. Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: Try writing the code. If it gets messy and hard then your going in the wrong direction. I think that is the same way I would start and if it for some reason did not pan out I would extract the logic seen in to a separate model.

Answer (score 0):

- add `seen` attribute/coulmn with default of 0 (ie not seen) to comments table with a migration.
- permit `seen` if you are using strong parameters or make it attribute accessible.
- in leads model show only those comments `if !comment.seen`
- when a user visits the leads model update seen attribute of all comments to 1 (seen)

Comment: but how would I use this for multiple users?

Comment: oh I didn't notice userS. You will probably have to use another model for seen as explained in the comment above. If I think of something I will let you know.